# JS: How to make the val() real-time

Tags: javascript, real-time, live, selector

Im having a issue here. Im using Valum´s file uploader, and i want to include a param. This param is albumID, aID, which should have the value of the album you selected. Although the javascript, that makes the button and where you make the settings, executes at document.ready. And because of this, it runs the albumPicker.val() immediatly, and therefore sets the albumPicker from the start to "1" (first album in the `<select>` i have is 1) and even if you pick another and upload a file, it wont take the changed one.

Here's the code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){     
            var album = $('#albumPicker').val()
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            action: 'php.php',
                allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
            debug: true,
                params: {
                aID : $('#albumPicker').val()
                },
                onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){ 
                    if(responseJSON.success){
                    $( '#'+$('#albumPicker').val() ).attr('src', [responseJSON.path].join(''));
                    }
                },
        });           
    });
```

Although the onComplete where it replaces a image, works just fine with the albumPicker.val(), because first when its completed the file upload it checks for the val().

What can I do about this? How can i solve this?

Comment: Just an FYI: `$(function() {});` is functionally equivalent to `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change params based on the state of your app, use

```
uploader.setParams({
   anotherParam: 'value' 
});
```

So on uploadButton.click just overwrite the parameter with it's realtime value. If that's not possible just hook into

`onSubmit: function(id, fileName){},`

you might still be able to change the parameters to reflect real time values on submit. Good luck.